# i need to fetch the column ,if one string is present in another column in same table using db2

Tags: db2

I am having an table t1 ,i need check the string c1 is present in c2 
(db2 query needed)

```
|C1    |C2      |
|------|--------|
|2     |235     |
|street|1 street|
|tomm  |angel   |
|25    |25 35   |
```

expected results :

### c1   c2

street : 1 street

25     : 25 35

Comment: Have you tried [locate](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000820.html) function, for example?

Comment: i have tried that ,but am not able to compare the column 1 and column2,if tried with locate function means we can able to search the specific string right ,i need to entire column generically

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Both operands of locate can be column names. '2' is a sub-string of '235'. Why don't we see the 1-st row in the result? Show your sql statement(s) you tried.

Comment: @mark  i dont want to check whether the operands/character  are present in another column , i want to fetch any of one string is present in another column (ex: winter season in column1 and summer season in coumn2  here season is matching ,so i need to fetch that ,if strings are not matching i need to ignore)

Comment: @shibu According to your example of matching `winter season` and `summer season` column values, the correct description of your goal would be getting rows, where the same **word** (and not `string`) exists in both column values. Is this the result you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following as is.
The idea is to tokenize each string in both columns assuming, that words are separated by one or more spaces. We join both list of words in the `exists` predicate to check, if there is a common word in both ones.

```
with t(c1, c2) as
(
values
  ('2', '235')
, ('street', '1 street')
, ('tomm', 'angel')
, ('25', '25 35')
, ('winter season', 'summer season')
)
select c1, c2
from t
where exists
(
select 1
from xmltable
(
'for $id in tokenize($s, "\s+") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' passing t.c1 as "s"
columns tok varchar(100) path '.'
) t1
join xmltable
(
'for $id in tokenize($s, "\s+") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' passing t.c2 as "s"
columns tok varchar(100) path '.'
) t2 on t1.tok = t2.tok
);
```

The result is:

```
|C1             |C2             |
|---------------|---------------|
|street         |1 street       |
|25             |25 35          |
|winter season  |summer season  |
```